Electronic drums and music through same amp
total newb I'm afraid. My son has an electric drum kit through an amp. He wants to play music through the amp using his phone and drum along at the same time. We tried a Ysplitter but only one channel, or the other worked. Not sure if it's the splitter or if we need something else. Volume not important as they can be controlled independently. Just need something cheap and simple.
It's an Ashton amp BPA18. The electric drum kit is an Alesis DM Lite. There's just one input into the amp, the kit has a phones output, aux in, r and l output (one goes to the amp).
Trying to plug the phone and the drum into the amp at the same time

(Regardless, "cheap and simple" might mean not bothering to combine them at all, just getting e.g. a bluetooth speaker for the phone.)

Aux in on the drum brain is 100% meant to do exactly what you’re trying to do. If you read the drum kit manual I’d bet a lot of money there’s a paragraph that says “for play along with your favorite tracks, plug your music player into the aux input”.

The amp has no aux input but the Alesis does. Use a 1/8 cable to plug the phone into the drum machine. It should send the phone to the main output combined with the drum sound but if it doesn’t at least the headphone jack should allow you to hear both at the same time.

Thanks so much everyone. No clue about this stuff. Will get the right cable and plug the phone into the drum

The correct tool to combine two audio sources is a mixer.  If you're lucky, the amp has multiple inputs and a built-in mixer, but it seems yours doesn't.
Many devices also have the ability to incorporate one external sound source via an "aux in" jack.  You will need a stereo male to male cable in the right size (most likely 3.5mm, sold as an "aux cord").
Never "Y" two active audio sources together with a simple splitter cable- while it may technically work with the right cable, you are directly connecting the two amps together, and they will try to drive each other.  This can cause one to fail.
